# Bootstrap Sizing smaller then 25%

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, height, sizing

I know bootstraps [sizing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/) that make an element as wide or as tall (relative to its parent). It support for 25%, 50%, 75%, and 100% by default. but I want an **smaller size than 25%**(I've no idea if it's possible or not). however manually i can use CSS `max-height` but that's not adopting and responsive.

Comment: don't remember much about bootstrap, been a while I don't use it, but I believe you could play with nesting things, I am not sure but maybe a 50% of a 25% could get you around 12.5% etc. I don't have time to try but maybe this works

Comment: hi sir thanks for replaying. nesting as ```<div class="mh-25"><div class="mh-25"> content </div></div>``` not working and nesting as  ```<div class="mh-25 mh-25"> content </div>``` too. how can i nest ?